# How can I make Excel copy my formatted date to another window and keep the format when some dates are full and some are only the year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a spreadsheet that has a date entered field.  That field is then put in another field further down the line, and then another field grabs ONLY the year from it.  So, DATE ENTERED, DATE, YEAR are my 3 fields.  The data entry person puts a date into the DATE ENTERED field however they want.  Say 3/9/89.  When it pulls it to the DATE field, the format is set to yyyy-mm-dd, so it changes it to 1989-03-09.  Then in the YEAR field, I have the code set to =TEXT(A1, "yyyy") where it puts "1989" in the field.

HOWEVER... if the data entry person only has the year, and put "1989" in the DATE ENTERED field, I get "1905-01-01" in the DATE field, and "1905" in the YEAR field.

Is there something I can put in the code that can be universal (same code in every DATE box) that would do this without me going in and changing all of the fields with just the year to "text" or "general"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some missing information because it shouldn't work quite the way you describe in the question.

**Here's what's happening**

Dates are stored as a day count since January 0, 1900 (1/1/1900 = day 1).  When you enter a string of characters that could represent a date, like `3/9/89`, Excel assumes that you intend it to be a date and converts it to one internally.  The actual string entered, `3/9/89`, isn't stored.  What is stored is `32576`, because 3/9/89 was the 32,576th day since 1/0/1900.

The cell formatting then determines how it is displayed.  Since Excel thinks the number is a date, it uses a default date format unless you have picked something else.

If your Date cell is just a cell reference to the input cell with a custom format of "yyyy-mm-dd", that just displays the same date with a different format.  It is still stored internally as `32576` in the Date cell.

Your Year cell is different.  If you tell it to display just the year of the date, with `=TEXT(A1, "yyyy")`, It figures out what the year is for day 32576, which is 1989, and stores `1989` as a text string (and displays that).

Based on the description in the question, here's what **should** happen if someone enters just `1989`.

First, it's just a four-digit number that doesn't translate to a specific date, so Excel will interpret it as a number rather than a date.  The Date Entered cell appears to have no specific format, so the value is displayed as the number `1989`.

The Date cell is formatted as a date, so that's how Excel interprets the value.  As a date, `1989` is the 1,989th day since 1/0/1900, or June 11, 1905.  The Date cell should display `1905-06-11`.  The Year cell calculates the year of day `1989` to be 1905, and displays that.

If you are seeing `1905-01-01` in the Date cell, there's another step going on.  That represents just the year, with no additional calendar units (e.g., days or months).  It's like what you would see from converting a year value to a date.

**So how to fix it?**

- Without changing anything, just instruct the data entry person to never enter just the year.  Instead of `1989`, they could enter `1/1/1989` so Excel recognizes it as a date.

Excel has a certain amount of intelligence to recognize dates, but it goes only so far.  If you want to be able to enter something outside of what Excel can recognize, you need to provide for that yourself. There are endless ways to do it depending on how fancy you want to get.  Some common approaches:

- You could check whether the input value is a number between X and Y, where X and Y are year limits for valid dates.  If so, you could build a date from it.  Excel has a DATE() function, which takes a specified year, month, and day, and converts that into an Excel date.  So for example, if you determine that an input number is meant to be a year, you could use it for the year parameter, and assign `1` for month and day.
- You could have separate input cells for year, month, and day, then build a date from that input.  The year specification could always be recognized as a year, even if nothing was entered for month and day (in which case, you could assign a value of `1` for those).
- You could do away with free-form entry and have pull-down menus to select the year, month, and day, and handle it as above.
- If year-only is acceptable for some records, decide whether you really need the full date for any records.  If not, just enter the year value (only) as a number or text rather than a date, and handle it that way afterwards.  Two-digit year entries can be converted to a four-digit format.  That eliminates the entire problem.  If the year is actually needed somewhere as a date (for date arithmetic), it is simple enough to convert it to a date.

  In this case, knowing you don't need the actual date, you could handle data entry differently.  Let the data entry person enter whatever's there, but test the input to see if it is an actual date.  If so, immediately convert it to a text or numerical year value.

Comment: Here's what I've tried recently:  

I changed the DATE field to have the function:  =TEXT(H22, "yyyy-mm-dd")
So what that does, is converts the date they enter in the DATE ENTERED box to the format I need.  Weirdly, this works if they know the month and year, or the entire year-month-day, but not if it's just the year.  
Which stinks, because I found the code:  =LEFT(T22, 4)
...for the YEAR field, and it works perfectly no matter what.  

I just need a single code that will work, so that I can build a template form to be filled out.  I work with volunteers so training is minimal.

Comment: @ArchivistG, Excel makes certain assumptions about dates.  If a pattern is entered that could be a legit month and year, it will assume it's a date and use the 1st day of the month.  A pattern that could be a legit month and day will be assumed to be in the current year.  Just a year isn't enough to be interpreted as a date.  And being interpreted as a date totally changes what gets stored and how that is interpreted.  (cont'd)

Comment: The safest way to force everything to be interpreted the way you want, regardless of what is entered, is to have an explicit entry for each date component; a year cell, a month cell, and a day cell.  They don't have to put in every value; you can substitute for missing values based on rules.  But 1989 in the year cell will always be a year.  If you want to display the entries as a complete date, plug the values into the DATE() function, then format that to display the date as you want.  If you only need the year, you already have that from the year entry; no conversion necessary.  (cont'd)

Comment: Short of that, you need to apply rules to test what was entered to make smarter determinations than Excel offers.  You can use an IF test to first check the entry to see if it is a number that falls in a range of legit year values.  That sounds like your primary exception, so that would let you handle it as a year.  If it doesn't qualify as a year value, you would assume it's a date and let Excel handle it.  Those are the best options for controlling and handling the input without user training.

Comment: If how to do it still isn't clear, pick an approach that would work in your situation and we can give you an example of what the code could look like.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've just settled with the idea that I'm going to have to have them enter it in yyyy-mm-dd format.  When that happens, and they're all set to text, it totally works.  Thanks!